Is there a way to include partition paths of the file path as a column in Azure Synapse SQL?
I have written parquet files in a path like this on the blob storage container: https://<my_blob_storage_accnt>.dfs.core.windows.net/current-snapshot/businesspartner=P1, https://<my_blob_storage_accnt>.dfs.core.windows.net/current-snapshot/businesspartner=P2, etc.
When I read the parquet files in Synapse SQL using OPENROWSET, like below --
SELECT
    TOP 100 *
FROM
    OPENROWSET(
        BULK 'https://<my_blob_storage_accnt>.dfs.core.windows.net/current-snapshot/**',
        FORMAT = 'PARQUET'
    ) AS [result]

I realized that the output table does NOT have businesspartner column. When I was using Spark/PySpark, I was able to do something like below to (source) see businesspartner as a column:
val df = sparkSession.read
  .option("basePath", path)
  .parquet(path + "/businesspartner=*/*.parquet")

I looked around and found these resources (1, 2 and 3). The closest approaches I can see, which are not quite natural for a SQL person like myself, are this approach, which suggests using WHERE filepath() = 'P1'
or as this approach suggests, to explicitly list individual blob paths for each partition to filter them like below:
SELECT
    TOP 100 *
FROM
    OPENROWSET(
        BULK (
'https://<my_blob_storage_accnt>.dfs.core.windows.net/current-snapshot/businesspartner=P1',
'https://<my_blob_storage_accnt>.dfs.core.windows.net/current-snapshot/businesspartner=P2'
),
        FORMAT = 'PARQUET'
    ) AS [result]

Is there a parameter in OPENROWSET or some other approach that would concisely allow me to read the whole suite of partitions as a column in the result table, from which I can use WHERE to filter the businesspartners if I wish to?
Thank you in advance for your answers/suggestions!

My brief research suggests that you're hosed. OPENROWSET doesn't seem to return metadata like the source file name for example as an extra column. Consider writing a script to accept the directory (with globbing) and loop through the files executing the query for each file, adding a columns in the script to the output based of the source filename.

@Bohemian - Thank you for the comment. :)

Assuming you are using SQL Serverless then you can pass a parameter to filepath as below (as documented here)
SELECT
    TOP 100 *,
            [result].filepath() AS WholePath,
            [result].filepath(1) AS Wildcard1,
            [result].filepath(2) AS Wildcard2
FROM
    OPENROWSET(
        BULK 'https://<my_blob_storage_accnt>.dfs.core.windows.net/current-snapshot/*=*/.parquet',
        FORMAT = 'PARQUET'
    ) AS [result]
WHERE [result].filepath(2) IN ('P1', 'P2')


Thank you, @Martin Smith. Your suggestion works (although I wish OPENROWSET makes it a parameter). :) The query that I ended up using (because it was a little different from what you stated above) was like this:
SELECT
TOP 100 ,
[result].filepath() AS WholePath,
[result].filepath(1) AS Wildcard1,
[result].filepath(2) AS Wildcard2
FROM
OPENROWSET(
BULK 'https://<my_blob_storage_accnt>.dfs.core.windows.net/current-snapshot/=/.parquet',
FORMAT = 'PARQUET'
) AS [result]
WHERE [result].filepath(2) IN ('P1', 'P2')
